# Where can I find a proof of the main properties of Weyl Curvature for semi-Riemannian manifolds?

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Most of the references I've seen deal with Riemannian geometry, rather than semi-Riemannian geometry. Chens monograph, *Pseudo-Riemannian Geometry, $\Delta$-Invariants and Applications* is one of the few that does deal comprehensively with semi-Riemannian manifolds, for example he derives the Codazzi-Mainardi equation in this context.

Whilst he mentions Weyl curvature (or conformal curvature) in the opening chapter and defines it, there are no proofs or references to proofs for any of the main properties. For example, he says it is 'well-known' that Weyl curvature vanishes identically in dimension 3 and is conformally invariant in higher dimensions (hence its alternative name).

Comment: The proofs are exactly the same as for Riemannian manifolds, especially if you don’t use an orthonormal frame.

Comment: @Deane Yang: Thanks for the tip.  I was looking for coordinate free proofs as Chen was able to provide this for the Gauss equation and the Codazzi-Mainardi equation. Using a frame, suggests that you are thinking of an indexful proof. Would this be the standard proof? I've seen one where the author actually starts from conformal invariance and derives the conformal tensor. I assume this would be roughly how Weyl would have first derived it.

Comment: Codazzi-Mainardi involves a single fixed metric. Proving conformal invariance involves looking at a family of metrics and their connections. This is trickier to do in a coordinate free way.